# How can I export the value of {this.props.price * this.state.quantity} so I could use it in a different .js file // a different react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { dumpLogs } from './Utils.js';



class RecCard extends Component {
     state = {
         quantity: null
     }

     incrementNumber = () => {
         this.setState((prevState, prevProp) => {
             return {quantity : prevState.quantity +1}
         });
     }

     decrementNumber = () => {
         this.setState((prevState, prevProp) => {
            return {quantity : prevState.quantity -1}
            
         });
     }

    render() {
    dumpLogs(this.props);
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
            <h5>{this.props.price} PLN</h5>
            <span>{this.state.quantity}</span> &nbsp; 
            <span className='hidden'>{this.props.price * this.state.quantity}</span> 
            <button onClick={this.incrementNumber}>+</button>
            <button onClick={this.decrementNumber} disabled={this.state.quantity <= null}>-
            </button>
        </div>

    )}
        
}



export default RecCard;
```

Comment: You can try using useContext take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502664/how-to-update-the-context-value-in-a-provider-from-the-consumer)

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, this is (most likely) a duplicate of
[This Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733595/how-can-i-export-a-variable-to-another-file-react) 
You should be able to export values using the `export` keyword. By assigning your `this.props.price * this.state.quantity` to a local variable and then exporting said variable (using `export MaxPrice`, or whatever you called that variable).